# Cannot press button in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am following a very simple iOS development tutorial where I have two UIButtons on a window.

I connected the buttons to the IBActions and the buttons are enabled for user interaction.

When I launch the application in the simulator, I cannot click on the buttons. The buttons don't even change color to blue to indicate that they are pressed.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Edit: Ok so my window does not have a view controller, I'm going to try and add one and see if it helps.

Comment: can you give tutorial link and screenshot of simulator

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair It's from the big nerd ranch guide book. The simulator only has 2 buttons on it nothing special, and I know that they have been connected properly. I've done a bit of iOS programming before, but I haven't faced this issue in XCode 3

Comment: is your view the first responder ? ... also why are still developing in Xcode 3 .. it is outdated for development now.

Comment: can you give me any link, so that I can view your code and can help you.

Comment: @Shubhank I'm developing in XCode 4

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair I can't it's a book

Comment: @Shubhank I checked my firstresponder and it seems that it is not connected to the buttons. I did connect them but still nothing is happening. Btw, I have the buttons connected to the app delegate too, should I be setting the appdelegate to be the first responder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable situation i can think of is that you didn't add button to the view..but just dropped in the IB and connected them .. in the view hierarchy on the left (in IB).. here will be

- File Owner
- First Responder
- View

Make sure the button are in the view...as in they are added to the view..

Comment: I don't have a view, I only have the window. Can that cause problems?

Comment: adding button to a window..no problem... but no view a big problem... let me explain .. you have a view ... apple provided view controller classes only so that any event happening on view can be reported and you can have your code run based on that... you have no view.. and no view controller... so button is there on the screen.. but window does not report touches by default.. so button aint getting touches.. i suggest creating a new class subclass of UIViewController.. it will have a xib file.. add the button to its view...

Comment: then in your app delegate.m import the class in APpdegate and then set window.rootviewcontroller to that view controller class...   simple solution to this is starting a new view based template project.. all these things are set up correctly in it

Comment: Thanks that does in fact solve the problem, I was trying to start from scratch. In the iOS programming big nerd ranch guide book they do not use a viewcontroller and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still having an issue - I will share my (strange) experience. The buttons worked great on my physical 7+ and the 8/8+ simulators. And even the first 3 screens of my app. On the 4th screen for iPhone 11, Pro, Pro Max the button to go to the next screen would not work when I pressed near the middle. I looked at everything; drove me crazy especially since I thought I'd tested this previously on the Pro Max. Then I decided to try pushing near the bottom right of the button - and it worked. So obviously the view was partially overlaying the button (near the bottom of the screen).  I hope this helps someone. Good luck with your development!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below link it may help you

[Link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/Create-UIButton-Programmatically.html)

Like to know if you need any further clarifications

Comment: I know how to create a button programmatically, I just want to know why it is not working when I do it from IB.

Answer (score -1):

Even you do not make connection to button it will appear on screen.. Something is wrong with simulator. Try deleting application from your project. 
Go to Project-> Clean and re run your project.